# C# List Lambda with index, object and DoStuff() / to array

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, generic-collections

Is there a way I can simplify this code?

```
double[] timeline = new double[dataList.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++){
          timeline[i] = dataList[i].position;
}

return timeline;
```

First thought:

```
new double[datalist.ToArray("lambda which selects all .position attributes") <- is this possible?
```

Second thought:

```
datList.Select((x, i) => timeline[i] = x)
```

Something link that but this doesn't work... I googled a lot, couldn't find any solution.

I want to simplify that because I love lamda expressions and I wanna learn more about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious here, why not simply use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
double[] timeline = dataList.Select(d => d.position).ToArray();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter why not use `var` here?

Comment: Because the question is about how to create a `double[]` with LINQ and because the type is not obvious. I just wanted to clarify that OP gets what he has asked for, `var` obfuscates this.

Comment: i tested that but tried double[] timeline = new double[dataList.Select(d => d.position).ToArray()]; and that got me an error cause it expected an int... i failed understanding the error message, thanks this work ! @TimSchmelter is there also a way to "do stuff" in the select lambda ? since its the only one you can get the index AND the object from

Comment: @ScriptWorld write a function and call it in the select: `items.Select((d,index) => SomeInportantFunction(d.position,index))`

Comment: @ScriptWorld: well, a LINQ query is not supposed to "do stuff". It's supposed to query some stuff. Don't let it cause side-effects. You would trigger them whenever you "touch" this query(f.e. calling `ToList` or enumerate it in a foreach). Instead query everything what you want to "do stuff" with. Then use a plain `foreach`-loop to actually do it.

Comment: @Chriz thanks ! thats a simple way, didnt know thats possible.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thats reasoned... i guess ill just stick to those foreach loops in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use projection (i.e. [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ method):

```
IEnumerable<double> timeLine = dataList.Select(dl => dl.position);
```

If you need to convert it to array, you can just use `ToArray` method